# drupal cache_set / cache_get expiration

Tags: caching

I have a function:

```
function _dc_election_races_get_articles($search_term)
{
    $search_url = 'http://feeds.example.com/vote_up/search.php?search='.rawurlencode($search_term);

    if ($cached = cache_get($search_url, 'cache'))
    {
        $results = $cached->data;
    }
    else
    {
        $results = json_decode(file_get_contents($search_url));
        cache_set($search_url, $results, 'cache', 60*60*3); //3 hours
    }

    return $results;
}
```

I basically want the cache to expire after 3 hours and re-fetch the data from the url. The  documentation on drupal made it seem like that it might not be removed from cache after 3 hours. Will cron cleanup caches?

Answer (score 3):

If you start chasing the code in [`cache_get`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21cache.inc/function/cache_get/7) you will eventually end up in [`DrupalDatabaseCache::getMultiple`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21cache.inc/function/DrupalDatabaseCache%3A%3AgetMultiple/7).  If you look at the code, you will see a call to [`DrupalDatabaseCache::garbageCollection`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21cache.inc/function/DrupalDatabaseCache%3A%3AgarbageCollection/7) at the top.  This will handle cache expiration before cron runs.

As part of [`system_cron`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.module/function/system_cron/7) you will see that [`cache_clear_all`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21cache.inc/function/cache_clear_all/7) get called with `NULL` as the first parameter which

> $cid: If set, the cache ID to delete. Otherwise, all cache entries that can expire are deleted.

This cleans up the cache tables every time cron runs.

The Drupal 6 plumbing is different for pruning the cache (start reading [`cache_get`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21cache.inc/function/cache_get/6), but the end result is essentially the same.

**TL;DR**, your cache TTL will always be honored when you get values, it's just the cache table cleanup that may not happen *exactly* when the TTL is up.

Comment: The cache is NOT expiring after 3 hours. What else could be causing this?

Comment: Try `cache_set($search_url, $results, 'cache', time() + 60*60*3); //3 hours from now`